# Handle Race Condition: Passport SignUp function works but responds with 404 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

For some reason, I'm getting a 404 error response with this code. It first does a successful 204 to signUp, then does a 404 error. Curiously, the user is being created in my database, a session is being created, and the user object is populating req.user. So everything is working but I'm getting a 404 error on the front end.

Front-End

```
signUp: async (email, password) => {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/signUp", {
          body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
          mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *include
          cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
          credentials: "include", // include, *include, omit
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          method: "POST",
        }).catch(error => this.setState({ isError: true }))
        if (res.ok) {
          this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true, isError: false })
        } else {
          console.log(res.status)
//this is running
          this.setState({
            isError: true,
          })
        }
```

Backend:

```
 app.post(
    "/signUp",
    (req, res, next) => {
      const email = req.body.email;
      const password = req.body.password;

      User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return next(err);
        }
        if (user) {
          return res.send({ message: "User Already Exists" });
        }
        const newUser = new User({
          email: email,
          password: password
        });
        newUser.save(next);
      });
    },
    passport.authenticate("login")
  );
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling signUp()

Comment: So the issue was just that I wasn't responding with anything. I figured passport.authenticate would automatically respond with something, but I guess it doesn't. 

The 404 error isn't really an error. It just means nothing was sent back and that everything, the route handlers, ran successfully

Answer (score 0):

I have two questions here:

1. Which strategy you are using here?..Because you used passport.authenticate('login').. I didn't remember any strategy like this
2. Why did you use passport.authenticate() at last?..Beacause usually passport.authenticate() will be in the middleware..

So am assuming, you are trying to use the passport for authentication in the `login` route. So try to write something like below:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```